# Django Break Loop in template

Tags: python, html, django, for-loop

Im currently displaying a table with values, and in case those values doesn't exist im displaying a button to introduce such values.
The problem is that i need a break in the for loop but Django doesn't support break in templates.

The current state is this:
[image]

And the html for the table is the following:

```
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
<th>Num de aluno</th>
   {% for quest in questionlist 
<th> {{quest.question_id.q_discription}} </th>
   {% endfor %}
</tr>
   {% for st in students %}
<tr>
<td> {{st.student_number}} </td>
   {% for qt in questionlist %}
<td>
{%for tst in studentexamitems %}
   {% if qt == tst.qitem_id and st == tst.student_id  %}
      {{tst.qscore}}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
<a href="{% url 'newTableEntry' qt.id st.id %}">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>&nbsp; Grade
   </button>
</a>
</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

So the question is how do i remove the button in case of a existing grade, and keep the button in case of not existing?

Comment: Django templates doesn't support `break`, update your context as required. It is not a good practise to implement logic in templates.

Comment: I know but this is the only way i could find to populate the table

Comment: It sounds like you're asking two different questions. Is it just that you want to hide the grade button when a numerical grade is available? That would be an `if`, not a `break`. Or is there some condition where you'd actually `break` out of the loop?

Comment: I don't understand the need for a break, it seems a `if ... else ...` is enough.

Comment: i just need to not display the button when the numerical grade is available. I think for that is necessary a break? or isn't?

Answer (score 0):

As stated on the comments, there is no `break` in Django template system.

You can still solve this using `if ... else`. 
If a grade is available, show the grade; if grade is not available, show the button.

```
{% for tst in studentexamitems %}
   {% if qt == tst.qitem_id and st == tst.student_id  %}
      {{tst.qscore}}
   {% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'newTableEntry' qt.id st.id %}">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>&nbsp; Grade
        </button>
    </a>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```